# Grabbing top 10 values per columns in a list of dataframes R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes of uneven columns and row lengths, and I'd like to extract only the top 10 elements of each columns the quickest way possible.

Example :

```
ex1 = data.frame(a = 1:20, b = 31:40)
ex2 = data.frame(a = 1:100)
ex3 = data.frame()
list = c()
list[[1]] = ex1; list[[2]] = ex2; list[[3]] = ex3
```

The output should be a list of data frames, with only the top and bottom 10 values of each column. For the ex1, that would look like a data frame with columns a and b. a would have 1-10 and 10-20, list[[2]] would house a data frame with elements 1:10 and 90:100, and list[[3]] would be empty.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `head` and `tail` and binding corresponding rows

```
lapply(list, function(x) rbind(head(x, 10), tail(x, 10)))
#[[1]]
#    a  b
#1   1 31
#2   2 32
#3   3 33
#4   4 34
#5   5 35
#6   6 36
#7   7 37
#8   8 38
#9   9 39
#10 10 40
#11 11 31
#12 12 32
#13 13 33
#14 14 34
#15 15 35
#16 16 36
#17 17 37
#18 18 38
#19 19 39
#20 20 40
#
#[[2]]
#      a
#1     1
#2     2
#3     3
#4     4
#5     5
#6     6
#7     7
#8     8
#9     9
#10   10
#91   91
#92   92
#93   93
#94   94
#95   95
#96   96
#97   97
#98   98
#99   99
#100 100
#
#[[3]]
#data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

Comment: Thought about using head and tail, but that would require that the dataframes be sorted. One solution was to use the order function, but that can't handle multicolumns as far as I know.

Comment: @christophervanhoecke You didn't mention that data was not ordered/needed to be ordered in your post. Also, `order` absolutely allows you to sort by multiple columns. For example `with(df, order(x, y, -z)` would order `df` first by `x`, then by `y` and then reverse order by `z`.

Comment: Just keep adding variables to `order` and it will nest them - `order(c(1,2,2),c(13,12,1))` for example.

Comment: Heads up, this *adds* data if a particular frame has fewer than 20 rows.

Comment: Suggest something like `lapply(list, function(x) rbind(head(x, 10), tail(x, min(10, nrow(x)-10))))`